# Call member function on a non-object, although the object exists

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a very weird thing going on here. I check in the AppController's beforeFilter() function, wether an id exists or not. It works when I open the url /project/user/1, but when I open /project/user/edit/1 it says that I use a function on a non-object. I already checked if I really do so, but I don't. I output the value with pr() and it shows me the object content.

Here is my beforeFilter() function:

```
$request = $this->request;

if (isset($request->params['id'])) {
            $model = Inflector::singularize(ucfirst($request->params['controller']));
            $cond = array('conditions' => array($model . '.id' => $request->params['id']));
            pr($this->{$model});
            exit;
            if (!$this->{$model}->find('first', $cond)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id.'), 'flash_notice');
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'manager' => (bool)$request->params['manager'],
                    'controller' => 'tournaments',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ));
            }
        }
```

The output of $model, before the id condition gets executed, contains the object data and is absolutley correct. I don't see the problem :/

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What function? What object (`var_dump()` it)? What line?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: If the error msg said it is non-object, then it is.

Comment: is `projects` your controller or a route?

Comment: Eh guys seriously... the error message is wrote above: call to a member function on a non-object - lol 

I edited the code above. pr($this->{$model}) outputs an "User Object" array and is totally correct. But inside the if-condition it says I call the find()-function on a non object rofl..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->request`?

Comment: Ah forgot `$request = $this->request` which stands on the top.

Comment: Is that seriously the entire message, verbatim? No *"member function X on non-object Y on line Z"*? At least the exact *line* would be important.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\prizeplay\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 67 - Line 67: `if (!$this->{$model}->find('first', $cond)) {` - The error occures because {$model} seems not to be an object, but it is! When I open /project/user/1 it works, but not when I open /project/user/guestbook/1 - but why? `$model` is definatley an object.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the error...

The code just simply doesn't work, when the URL you open has some other error for example a database connection error. It's hard for me to explain but when I removed the code above and opened my URL an error like this came:

> Database Error
>
> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'isAdmin'
>   at line 1

When I fixed that bug, the code above works fine.